# Why Tensorflow model is consuming huge time during 1st epoch rather then other epochs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a Image dataset with 32000 images with labels. I used Tensorflow.data.Dataset API for input data pipeline. But During my first epoch it's taking huge time compared with other epochs.
[image]

Here is my Code:

```
### preaparing Data set
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")


labels = train['label']


one_hot_label = to_categorical(labels)
columns =  ["cbb", "cbsd", "cgm", "cmd", "healthy"]
train[columns] = one_hot_label
#train.head()

data_dir = pathlib.Path("train_images")
filenames = list(data_dir.glob('*.jpg'))
print("image count: ", len(filenames))
print("first image: ", str(filenames[0]))


fnames=[]
for fname in filenames:
  fnames.append(str(fname))
  

filelist_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(fnames)

ds_size = filelist_ds.cardinality().numpy()

train_ratio = 0.9

train_data = filelist_ds.take(train_ratio*ds_size)
valid_data = filelist_ds.skip(train_ratio*ds_size)


def get_label(file_path):
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '\\')
  file_name= parts[-1]
  label = train[train["image_id"]==file_name][columns].to_numpy()
  return tf.squeeze(tf.convert_to_tensor(label))


def process_image(image):

    #Don't use tf.image.decode_image, or the output shape will be undefined
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)

    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=32.0 / 255.0)
    image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)

    #This will convert to float values in [0, 1]
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

    resized_image = tf.image.resize(image, [128, 128])
    return resized_image


def combine_images_labels(file_path: tf.Tensor):
    image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    image = process_image(image)
    label = get_label(file_path)
    #label = reshape_label(label)
    return image, label


ds_train = train_data.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(combine_images_labels, [x], [tf.float32,tf.float64]),num_parallel_calls=4)
ds_test = valid_data.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(combine_images_labels, [x], [tf.float32,tf.float64]),num_parallel_calls=4)


ds_train_batched=ds_train.batch(BATCH_SIZE).cache().prefetch(4)
ds_test_batched=ds_test.batch(BATCH_SIZE).cache().prefetch(4)


base_model=ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False, input_shape = (128,128,3)) 
#base_model.summary()

x= base_model.output


for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False

#new_x  = model.output
x=Flatten()(x)
x=Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)
preds=Dense(5,activation='softmax')(x)

model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse',metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalCrossentropy()])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model_1.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, monitor='loss', mode='max')

history = model.fit(
               ds_train_batched,
               epochs=100,
               steps_per_epoch=10,
               verbose=1,
               callbacks=[checkpoint],
               validation_data=ds_test_batched)
```

Actually, There is no error. But, It takes a huge time for 1st epoch. How can reduce this training time?

Comment: Perhaps some warm-up/disk read? Would be hard to answer without specific info. // Also you should post the console content as text.

Comment: I am using tensorflow-gpu==2.4.0, CUDA=11.1  but I idn't understand about posting the console content as text

Comment: I mean, don't just post it as a screenshot.

Comment: Although I think hard disk read time is the most likely --  in that case there's nothing you can do about it. (generally, tensorflow is pretty good)

Comment: [This thread could help](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13114).